# R. net read file exception

Tags: r, readfile, r.net

I wrote the following code:

```
      REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();

      REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
      engine.Evaluate("dataset<-read.table('C:\\Users\\b-mobela\\Documents\\Temp\\data.txt')")
```

I get the exception:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in RDotNet.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

When instead of giving the file location I use file.choose() it works. Why???

Answer (score 2):

Answer coming a little late, but I came here while searching for the same problem. You need to use the forward slashes in the path:

```
    engine.Evaluate("dataset<-read.table('C:/Users/b-mobela/Documents/Temp/data.txt')")
```